# error for inserting data in database in view in joomla

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I want to insert a data in database but it show error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getform() on a non-object in
>   \components\com_enquiry\views\form\view.html.php
>   on line 9

my code is:
enqiry.php:

```
public function getform($data)
{
    $db=JFactory::getDbo();
    $db=$this->getDbo();
    $query=$db->getQuery(true);
    $reg=new stdClass();
    $reg->name=$data['name'];
    $reg->email=$data['email'];
    $reg->phone=$data['phone'];
    $reg->comments=$data['comments'];
    $reg=$db->insertObject('#__enquiry',$reg);
}
```

and view.html.php:

```
public function display()
{
    $this->msg = 'enquiry form';
    $model=$this->getModel(); 
    $data =$model->getform();
    $this->assignRef('data', $data );
    parent::display();
    parent::display();
}
```

controller:

```
     class enquiryController extends JControllerLegacy
      {
      public function display()
       {
         $vname=JRequest::getCmd('view','form');
         JRequest::setVar('view',$vname);
         JRequest::setVar('layout','default');  
         parent::display();
       }

     public function show()
     {
    $data['name']=$_POST['name'];
    $data['email']=$_POST['email'];
    $data['phone']=$_POST['phone'];
        $data['comments']=$_POST['comments'];
    $sname=JRequest::getCmd('view','thanx');    
    JRequest::setVar('view',$sname);
    print_r($data);
     }
   }
```

could someone help me solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your model is not loaded by the line:

```
$model=$this->getModel();
```

This either means that your model in enquiry.php is not named correctly

```
ComponentNameModelEnquiry
```

or that your view is not named enquiry.

You can try to specify which model you want, like

```
$model = $this->getModel('enquiry');
```

Comment: i does not understand where should i make the changes

Comment: Can you include the view and model file declarations? We don't need the controller.